# How to toggle a table row when another one is clicked

Tags: jquery, toggle

Well.. my English is short....sorry!

This code as you see gets some data from DB and builds a table:

```
.answer{display: none;}

<c:forEach var="quest" items="${list }">
    <c:if test="${quest.qkind==1 }" var="1">
        <tr class="queset">
            <th >${quest.no }</th>
            <td>${quest.question }</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="answer ~~~~">
            <th></th>
            <td span="cols=2">${quest.contents }</td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

When I click a row with class `.queset` I would like to toggle the corresponding hidden row with class `.answer`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your English is not short, your question is.

Comment: what do you mean by toggle ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek: jQuery toggle()

Comment: or you can also use `slideToggle()` for smooth transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm VERY unfamiliar with the server-side language you are using, so may not work as-is.

```
<c:forEach var="quest" items="${list }">
    <c:if test="${quest.qkind==1 }" var="1">
        <tr class="queset" data-question="${quest.no }">
            <th >${quest.no }</th>
            <td>${quest.question }</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="answer" data-answer="${quest.no}">
            <th></th>
            <td span="cols=2">${quest.contents }</td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.queset').click(function() {
    $('tr[data-answer="'+$(this).data('question')+'"]').toggle();
});
```

**Demo**

[Check out a working demo (without server-sides scripting).](http://jsfiddle.net/h653e/2/)